# div sidebar error correction in php paging

Tags: php, css, html, navigation, paging

Wrapper
center div

### sidebar div

when click **"sidste"** button that are the last page in php paging.
Sidebar div content moves under center div.

[image: navigation paging php css]

The webpage is responsive but navigation is giving this error problem.
Where can the problem be?

css:

```css
.wrapper
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left:  auto;
     width: 100%;      
     max-width: 1280px;
     padding-right: 10px;
     padding-left:  10px;
     overflow: hidden;


   .divcenter
    float: left;      
    width: 70%; 
    margin-bottom:3px;
    padding: 1.25em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear:both;
    border:3px solid  #ccc;
    margin-left:110px;
    


   .divrightsidebar
    float:right;
    width: 30%;
    margin:0px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    padding: 1.25em;
    word-wrap: break-word
    margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: We are missing the relevant part to be able to help you, if it happens on click, we must know what happens to the CSS styles when clicked. A live example would actually be nice in this case

Comment: I have solved it myself now but thanks for your help kaddath.